# Force download itextsharp created anchor in PDF

Tags: pdf, itext

I need to develop application which creates pdf files and serve them via http. PDF is created using iTextSharp. In my pdf files are lot of anchors navigating to images and videos stored on the same server f.e. `http://192.168.10.10/video.mp4` .

Files are generated and trasmitted via http correctly, but when I click on those anchors in my pdf source files are opening in browser. I would like to force download them.

I read all itextsharp documentation and cannot find anything. 
Is there some way to do that?

Comment: Your heading says "delete"; your text says "download". Now which is it?

Comment: I have no idea why... Distraction I think, header is corrected now.